# Are there any types of adhesive which are designed to be easily soluble in strong acid (HCl with pH 1-4)?

Tags: acid-base, adhesion

I am a mechanical engineer so forgive my ignorance in chemistry. I know there are water soluble adhesives like polyvinyl alcohol but I am wondering if there are glues which easily dissolve in low pH HCl without the need for scrubbing or much perturbation.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! I don't quite get the need why it has to be acidic and there are probably quite a number of water soluble glues out there. There are probably various degrees of adhesion, so I guess there can't be a general answer to this question. If you could add more detail and context, you'll probably get a more meaningful answer.

Comment: Rather than use strong acids, chlorinated solvents will be better e.g.  dichloromethane.

Comment: You might look up the chemical compatibility for a number of adhesives that are otherwise suitable for your purposes. For example, https://www.norlandprod.com/techrpts/chemresit.html shows NaOH (a strong *alkali*), attacks its product. That said, if an adhesive is sandwiched between to impermeable surfaces, chemicals may not be able to infiltrate to dissolve the adhesive.